# scrape data (rate) from website

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape this rate ("5.55") off the website bellow and import it into google spreadsheets. i tried hard many times and only ERROS as an answer came out and I know that have already been questions about it.

Website: http://www.alphatransfers.co.uk/

I tried both:

1) IMPORTXML(B3,/html[@class='js']/body[@class='home page page-id-55 page-template-default template-slider  with_aside aside_right color-custom style-default layout-full-width header-modern sticky-header sticky-white subheader-title-left nice-scroll']/div[@id='Wrapper']/div[@id='Content']/div[@id='content_home']/div[@class='content_wrapper clearfix']/div[@class='sidebar sidebar-1 four columns']/div/form[@id='bottom_form']/div[@class='mkt_strip'][2]/span[@id='mkt_rate_02'])

2) =IMPORTXML(B3,"//div[@class=`mkt_strip']|//div[@class='span_id']")

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basic purpose of getting the pure value the formula you want to use is this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.alphatransfers.co.uk/","//*[@id='mkt_rate_02']")
```

and if you want to clean up the extra space and the colon use this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("http://www.alphatransfers.co.uk/","//*[@id='mkt_rate_02']"),": ","")
```